# SQL (DQL): WHERE value IN (array field1) OR field2 = value

Tags: sql, sql-server, symfony, dql

I'm using Symfony 2. I have Entity **Ent1** with Field1 = ManyToMany(targetEntity=Ent2), and Field2 = OneToOne(targetEntity=Ent2).

ManyToMany involves an intermediate table in DataBase.

My request parameter is an instance of Ent2 (in DQL, which means an Id of Ent2 for SQL) '*myEnt*', I need to select all Ent1 entities having '*myEnt*' IN (Field1 array) OR having Field2 = '*myEnt*'.

In pseudo-SQL it would be

```
SELECT(*) FROM Ent1 
(WHERE Field2='myEnt' OR INNERJOIN(Ent2 ON Ent2 = 'myEnt')
```

which is not functionnal, of course.

Is it possible? 
If it is, do someone have the correct logic/syntax to reach that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the join part to select the rows to join on and the where to filter so you may need something like this:

```
SELECT(*) FROM Ent1 
inner join ent2
on ent1.id = ent2.id 
 WHERE Field2='value' OR  Field2.id = 'value'
```

Comment: I realize my syntax logic in my pseudo SQL exemple was wrong, sorry.
I think you misunderstood my aim: I want to select all Ent1 lines which have either 'MyEnt' value in Ent1.Field1 (Ent1.Field1 = MyEnt) OR having 'MyEnt' IN (Ent1.Field2 array, which is an array of Ent2 entities)